# Sql DataBase does not update changes

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

I get the error message below

> Dynamic sql generation for the update command is not supported against a select command that does not return any key column information

when I try to update my database via a button click after I made changes in `GridView`. Below is the code:

```
private void updateDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlAdapter(@"SELECT [Customer],[Employee],[Product],[State] FROM [Table1]", connection);
    sqlCmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlAdapter);
    DataTable datTable = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
    sqlAdapter.Update(datTable);
}
```

I have searched a lot to find a solution but I can't find something useful. I know that this is because a `PrimaryKey` is missing in my database but it is supposed that there is none.

So how can I update my database after changes were made without having a `PrimaryKey` defined? Is it possible to use another way where I can only use my column names and the tablename (I have only found a solution where each element has to be written manually and that's too much)?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a data-query as an update-query?

Comment: Without a primary key (or without a combination of fields that uniquely identifies a single record) you will have hard times to update records with automatic updates

Comment: Error message is very clear: **does not return any key column** - you need to select id (or what is you primary key of Table1).

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The sqlAdapter query? because else it doesn't seem to work. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I have no Primary Key and I don't want to use one - That's the problem.

Comment: OK, forget for a moment your code, go to your Sql Server Management Studio and find a query that could Update a single record in your table. If you are able to find a valid syntax then create an SqlCommand with that and use it instead of the DataAdapter.Update method. (then make the same for Delete ops)

Comment: So you probably need to manually set update query. Generation is simple, taking PK and using it in update query. Now, how generator will know how to format your update query without it?

Comment: This should work with every database so that the user hasn't to define something in his database. So it should work only with the code.

Comment: No PK = broken database design = useless, garbage data + horrid performance. Once this is fixed and the database is made useful (with keys and whatnot) then this issue "fixes itself". without a pk there can be no meaningful interaction with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you will update the DataTable, not your database. You can read this [Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
  SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlAdapter(@"SELECT [Customer],[Employee],[Product],[State] FROM [Table1]", connection);
  sqlCmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlAdapter);
  DataTable datTable = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
  sqlAdapter.Update(datTable);
  sqlAdapter.Dispose();// SqlDataAdapter must be Disposed !
```

From your question

> when I try to update my database via a button

If you want to update your database you need an update query and to call ExecuteNonQuery() of the SqlCommand. You should Insert/Update into your database with adding/updating any of the records in the grid.

Comment: Ok but this is hard coded and I need to write it myself. Is ith possible to do something like that when I change the values directly in GridView and then make him read them (even if he should read and rebuild the whole datatable)? The main thing is that he reads the GridView just how it's shown to the user

Comment: ONLY IF YOUR TABLE HAS A PRIMARY KEY! Sorry for shouting but you can' have it both ways. If you want convenience, implement a PK, so everything can work automatically. Without a PK, the code doesn't know how to uniquely identify a record and how to update so you need to manually tell it. You really should try and understand the importance of a primary key. A table without a PK is a toy that will be broken.

Comment: And I strongly suggest that you do not simply add an identity column. You need to look at what is stored in your table and consider what combination of columns should be unique and use that. Is the table storing information about Customers? Then you should make customer unique. Is it storing info about the relationship between customers and products? then customers and products should be unique. Don't just slap on an identity column of there is a valid business key

Answer (score 1):

"a Primary Key is missing in my database but it is supposed that there is none"

This is your problem. Without a primary key, the DataAdapter cannot work out which row to update, so fails when you try.

As you point out, you could write the update SQL manually, but if you have a table with rows that need to be updated individually then a primary key is the way to go.

Comment: How could I update that manually every time when the "Update" button is clicked?

Comment: As other commenters have pointed out, if you can't uniquely identify a row, then you're not going to be able to update the row. If you can uniquely identify a row, then that unique information that does identify the row is a defacto composite primary key.